# Manipulate text string with many "s in order to paste function on rows in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I'm trying to create a loop which pastes a formula based on an index value but I'm running into a problem since the string has many "s. I want to paste the formula in this way since I'm pulling data from an API and I can't access the API data in a loop.

I made the following code for a formula

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim r As Long

r = 10
StartRow = 3
LastRow = Range("I" & StartRow).End(xlDown).Row

For i = StartRow To LastRow
Range("B" & r).Value = "=BCurveStrip(I" & i & ")"

r = r + 1
Next i
```

This returns in cell "B"

```
          "B"
10    =BCurveStrip(I3)
11    =BCurveStrip(I4)
12    =BCurveStrip(I5)
13    =BCurveStrip(I6)
```

I want to do  the same for a formula which is a bit more complicated and looks like this:

```
=BCurveFwd(B13;"startdate,maturity,par.mid";B22;C22;B23;C23;"cols=3;rows=1")
```

And the loop to return this

```
14    =BCurveFwd(B10;startdate,maturity,par.mid";B22;C22;B23;C23;"cols=3;rows=1")
15    =BCurveFwd(B11"startdate,maturity,par.mid";B22;C22;B23;C23;"cols=3;rows=1")
16    =BCurveFwd(B12"startdate,maturity,par.mid";B22;C22;B23;C23;"cols=3;rows=1")
17    =BCurveFwd(B13"startdate,maturity,par.mid";B22;C22;B23;C23;"cols=3;rows=1")
```

on rows 14 to 17 for example.

I have tried

```
r = 14
StartRow = 10
LastRow = Range("B & StartRow).End(xlDown).Row

For i = StartRow To LastRow
Range("B" & r).Value = "=BCurveFwd(B" & i & ";"startdate,maturity,par.mid";B22;C22;B23;C23;"cols=3;rows=1")"

r = r + 1
Next i
```

I understand that the problem lies in that I don't know how to manipulate a text string with " in it. As Always, any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: To refer to a `"` within a text string, you generally need to either enter a double quote `""` or concatenate the ASCII code (34). If you were to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), there might be a simpler method of accomplishing your goals.

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld, thanks for your comment and you're. It would have been better to ask for somelike how to create a text string called "strawberries" or sommething

Answer (score 1):

Double up your included quotes:

```
"=BCurveFwd(B13;""startdate,maturity,par.mid"";B22;C22;B23;C23;""cols=3;rows=1"")"
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work unfortunately but thanks. I figured that the easiest solution was just to pick up string with  " from a cell and then combine it. Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: @AndreasHild Probably you need to change the separator to a comma within the formula, as mentioned by chris neilsen

Answer (score 1):

In addition to properly escaping your quotes, since you are writing to `.Value` you need to use the US centric parameter delimiter `,` rather than `;` (same applies if you use `.Formula`).

If you prefer to stick to your local flavour  write to `.FormulaLocal`

Comment: Good Point, I changed the language settings which made Everything easier. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the following

I put

```
,"startdate,maturity,par.mid",B22,C22,B23,C23,"cols=3;rows=1")
```

in cell G32 and then I just did

```
text1 = Range("G32").text
For i = StartRow To LastRow

Range("B" & r).Value = "=BCurveFwd(B" & i & text1

r = r + 1
Next i
```

Not the most elegant solution but it did the job. Thx everyone